R/plotly: how to project an arbitrary line to (x,y), (x,z) or (y,z) plane?
In many online resources we know how to project the contours of a surface.  For example, in section "Surface Plot With Contours" from https://plotly.com/r/3d-surface-plots/.   The method is to use argument contours in plotly::add_surface and specify project=list(z=TRUE).
My question is, how to project an arbitrary line on the surface (in either x, y, or z direction)?   This arbitrary line is defined using plotly::add_paths.
A dumb solution is to plot the projected curve on the (x,y) plane where z=0.
Is there a smarter solution, as in the case of contours, that the projected curve stays on the  (x,y) grid when I change plotly::layout(scene = ...) ?
library(plotly)

dim(volcano) # [1] 87 61 

f1 = plot_ly(z = ~volcano)
add_surface(
  p = f1,
  contours = list(z = list(show = TRUE, usecolormap = TRUE, project = list(z = TRUE)))
) # projection of contours, great!

# use a lighter color scale
(f2 = plot_ly(z = ~volcano) |> add_surface(colorscale = list(c(0, 1), c('beige', 'lightgreen'))))

# add an arbitrary line
(f3 = add_paths(f2, x = 0:60, y = 0:60, z = volcano[cbind(1:61,1:61)], line = list(width = 4)))

# now how do I project this arbitrary line to (x,y), (x,z) or (y,z) plane ?

# dumb solution
# draw the projected curves on (x,y=0,z) and (x=0,y,z) plane manually
f3 |>
  add_paths(x = 0, y = 0:60, z = volcano[cbind(1:61,1:61)], line = list(width = 3)) |>
  add_paths(x = 0:60, y = 0, z = volcano[cbind(1:61,1:61)], line = list(width = 3))

# do we have a smarter solution?


This works for plotting a line, even one you randomly choose. However, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do your data creation for add_paths.
I'm sure there is more than one way to do this, but this works for me.
First, I set up the data as x, y, z. Since this is a matrix of elevations, I need to know what the grid is, then I use that build x & y, then I collapse z.
dim(volcano)
# [1] 87 61 

volc <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(0, 60, by = 1), 87),        # grid is 61 x 87
                   y = rep(seq(0, 86, by = 1), each = 61),
                   z = as.vector(t(volcano)))

Now I can build whatever I want on the surface using this data. Straight lines are pretty straightforward, filter for x == ... or y == ....
I can use add_paths or add_trace(type = "scatter3d", mode =...
add_trace(f2, type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines",  # with trace, where y = 50
          data = volc[volc$y == 50, ], x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z)
                                                   # with paths, where y = 50
add_paths(f2,  data = volc[volc$y == 50, ], x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z)



If wanted a line between (0, 70) and (50, 20) I can do that using the formula for a line.
First a UDF, to make this a bit easier - using the to and from coordinates and the data frame (as dfa). The coordinates can be in any order, as long as they are x, y, x, y order.
It can be a bit hard to see the line in the images here, so I've added markers to make it more visible.
cords <- function(x0, y0, x1, y1, dfa) {
  mx <- ifelse(x0 != x1, which(c(x0, x1) == max(c(x0, x1))), 2)
  dx <- c(x0, x1)[mx] - c(x0, x1)[-mx]  # change in X
  dy <- c(y0, y1)[mx] - c(y0, y1)[-mx]  # change in Y                          
  intc <- dy/dx * x0 - y0               # y-intercept     
              # find the relevant rows, using Ax - By + C = 0
 with(dfa, which(dy * x - dx * y - dx * intc == 0))
}     # returns row indices in dfa


add_trace(f2, type = "scatter3d", mode = "lines+markers", # use both for hi-vis
          marker = list(size = 2),                        # but a bit smaller...sheesh
          data = volc[cords(0, 70, 50, 20, volc), ],      # call the line maker for coords
          x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z)





Thank you so much for the attention, Kat!!   My question is how to project this line (that we created) to (x,y) or (x,z) or (y,z) plane.    My gut feeling is that Plotly does not offer this feature.

In a Plotly surface plot, you can project contours to a plane; you can split the surface project into several planes - but I don't think you can choose a different plane for projection. Plotly's type = "mesh3d"gives you projection axis choice with the argument delauneyaxis (Delaunay triangulation). In my notes I've written for the xy plane, you wouldn't need this argument (it's default). When you want the zx plane (where xyz -> zxy), use delauney = "x". When you want the yz plane (where xyz -> yzx), use delauney = "y".

Thanks again, Kat!  I just realized my original code has bugs, not sure how they evade me haha.   I am still looking for the answer, but thanks a lot for your suggestions!
